# Excel VLOOKUP issue

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a problem on a VLOOKUP function in an Excel.
Basically i am trying to search a route from another spreadsheet, using a reference number.
- example: I put in a reference (lets say WPC 80) and i want to get a route (for this ex it should be Pitesti - Wrzesnia: [image: Excel Sheet]
[image: Excel Sheet]

The problem is that it gives me something random.
I know that maybe im not using it correctly, but do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Change TRUE to FALSE

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) documentation, the last parameter contols whether to use Exact Match or Approximate Match.

Try using exact matching:

```
=VLOOKUP(..., FALSE)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer.
This doesnt work, because as you see the parameters aren`t the same.
i am searching WPC 80 in a list that doesnt have the number at the end. (WPC)
I also tried to use partial lookup (VLOOKUP(E6,INFO!$A$13:$T$16&"*",2,TRUE)
but this doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not enough rep to post a comment.  When using vlookup, and the Range_Lookup parameter is TRUE, the lookup table must be ***sorted in ascending order***, or you will get unusual results.  Also ensure you put an absolute reference on the lookup table for when you drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

Better use **INDEX** and **MATCH** combination, faster and far more reliable.